# Inquiry about the vs2010 property sheet

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a basic program set from my instructor. There are basically two parts: 
     1. There is a library program which student should compile it first.
     2. There are several example programs that should use the "support" from the library program.

The screenshot of the property manager is shown here:[image]

I think the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheet could be used for the global settings;

The osgVirtualEnvironment is the name of library program. But it seems there is no proper sheet named by example1 solution?(Because I think there should be a property sheet for local includings and libs settings)

Moreover, there are two property sheets named by the library program: osgVirtualEnvironment APP, 
osgVirtualEnvironment Library. It seems I need to set the User Macros for both two property sheets in  order to do the #include<>

My questions are：

1.Why there are two property sheets named from the library program and no property sheet named after the example program?

2.The User Macro of the osgVirtualEnvironment Library(one property sheet), the name is OSGVE_DIR, with Value: $(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\..    the path of SolutionDir means the path of osgVirtualEnvironment.sln or the path of osgVirtualEnvironment Library Debug.props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is, "Why is there no property sheet for my project", then the answer is:

It's not necessary.  Property sheets are so you can re-use properties across multiple projects.  If you want to edit the properties of just your project, you can do that from the main menu "Project->Properties".

As for why there are two property sheets for that library, I don't know.  Ask your teacher, he's the one who set it up for you, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please give me some clue about my 2nd question?